# Adding jQuery dependency breaks meanJS application

Tags: jquery, angularjs, meanjs

I have a meanJS application that was using jQlite but now needs full jQuery functionality. When I added the jquery dependency to all.js:

```
lib: {
        css: [
            'public/app.css',
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
            'public/lib/angular/angular-csp.css'
        ],
        js: [
            'public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/Chart.js/Chart.js',
            'public/lib/momentjs/min/moment.min.js',
            'public/lib/momentjs/min/locales.min.js',
            'public/lib/humanize-duration/humanize-duration.js',
            'public/lib/angular-timer/dist/angular-timer.js',
            'public/lib/countdown360/dist/jquery.countdown360.js'
        ]
    },
```

every page I load now tries to bootstrap angular twice. One function call is from my code file, `application.js`, and the second function call, the one that throws the error, is coming from `VM703`, which has the same text as the actual file.

Why is my code running from a non file and how I stop it? The only time I've seen VMx before as a file is if my console commands throw errors, or on sites like jsFiddle/codepen that create "files" to run.

EDIT: "Breaks" refers to bootstrapping the application a 2nd time. My application.js file runs, bootstrapping angular as desired, then a virtual copy of it runs, throwing an error and appearing to permanently slow down the webpage.

Comment: Is it saying "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once" in your console?

Comment: Yes. Sorry meant to explicitly state that is what is meant by "breaks".

Comment: By any chance, aren`t you loading angular.js already in your main html?

Comment: yes, it appears VMx in this instance is referencing a script tag with inline code. I missed it earlier because for some reason, one I can't think of why the MEAN team would have done it like this, it removes the script tag after it finishes its execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might solve your issue.

When you add JQuery, your application evaluates twice tags inside an `ng-view`, thus, I am assuming your scripts are loading in the `<body>`, where you placed your `ng-view`. If so, moving your `ng-view` into a `<div` does it as well as moving your `<script>` to `<head>`

Comment: Is ng-view an implicit or explicit directive? Because ng-view does not occur in my code.

Comment: It is implicit. Well, I was working with this assumption. You'd usually use with `$routerProvider`. Check this guys' problems, they also added JQuery. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050158/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-because-of-jquery-why)