# jQuery dependency above Angular one: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once

Tags: jquery, angularjs, gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I am working on a Yeoman Angular-generated folder. I installed through Bower a module that requires jQuery. Grunt's wiredep places the jQuery dependency above the AngularJS in the `index.html`, as follows:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
...
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This seems reasonable, as jQuery doesn't depend on Angular.

The thing is that when I try to load my app in the browser, I get the following message in JS console:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
VM80711:26293 
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

angular-animate.js:442 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

If I manually swap the `jQuery` dependency with the `angular` one at `index.html`, everything works like a charm, but when I `grunt build` my app, default order is set, so I can't get the working configuration in the dist folder.

`bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "webapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.14",
    "angular-material": "~0.9.0",
    "restangular": "~1.5.1",
    "angular-slick": "~0.2.1",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "~1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "app"
}
```

Really appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternatives to removing/reordering jquery.js : 
if your `index.html` is using `<ui-view />` then try changing it to this: `<ui-view></ui-view>` because of how HTML5 handles tags as explained in this [SO post about tag syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5/3558200#3558200) 
secondly, do a check of your `routes`, as explained in this [SO post about referencing the view incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27028147/4245493) :

example:
`templateUrl: 'myView/myPage.html'` check the spelling and capitalization

Comment: Thanks, Shehryar! The issue was the `<ui-view/> thing`. I still wonder why this happens at the dependency import switching.