# Tried to load angular more than once with MVC4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I installed AngularJs with MVC4 using `Nuget` package and created a `bundle` for AngularJS

```
 bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/scripts")
                .Include("~/Scripts/angular.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

In Layout I included it as follow:

```
 @Scripts.Render("/scripts/angular-route.js")
  @Scripts.Render("/scripts/loginController.js")
  @Scripts.Render("/scripts/routeConfig.js")
```

**routeConfig.js**

```
angular
    .module('MyApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'MyApp.ctrl.crud',
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/Index',
          //  controller: 'loginController'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/loginPage',
            controller: 'crudController'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }]);
```

**loginController.js**

```
angular
    .module('MyApp.ctrl.crud', [])
    .controller('loginController', [
        '$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            alert("In Login Controller")
        }
    ]);
```

When I program is display following exception:

**WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.**

Why I get this Warning?

Comment: Are you trying to load partial views in your `Index` or `LoginPage`? This error can appear if you get full page instead of a partial. Say, for example, you expect a partial view (withour `_Layout.cshtml`) but there's an exception on the server and it sends the error page, which might not be a partial.

Comment: I get this too, searched around and found some answers on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765941/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-when-i-include-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580640/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-with-mvc4