# AngularJS Tried to load more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

My Angular JS app is displaying this message in the console :

> angular.min.js tried to load more than once.

The app is fully working but is loading all the ajax requests several times before having any response.

I really don't understand what is could be. I don't even know what code to show you.

If anyone wants to help me, just tell me what part of my code you'd like to see and I'll copy paste it here...

thank you

## UPDATE :

index.blade.php :

```
@extends('master')

@section('controller') ng-controller="AppController" @endsection

@section('content')

<div class="app" id="app"
     ng-class="{'app-header-fixed':app.settings.headerFixed, 'app-aside-fixed':app.settings.asideFixed, 'app-aside-folded':app.settings.asideFolded}"
     ui-view></div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/moment.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.__user = {{Auth::user()->toJson()}};
    window.__user_details = {{Auth::user()->details->toJson()}};
    window.__company = {{ Auth::user()->getCompany()->toJson()}}

    <?php if( Department::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->first() ): ?>
            window.__startDepartment = {{ Department::where('company_id','=',Auth::user()->company_id)->first()->id }}
    <?php endif; ?>
    @if(Auth::user()->user_level == 4)
        window.__companies = {{ Company::all()->toJson() }}
    @endif;
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<!-- Angular -->
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-load.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-jq.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/timer.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-load.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-jq.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-tree.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/timer.js"></script>
<!-- App -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/AppController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DemoControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/LeaveControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ReporterControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/TimeslotControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/TasksControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/MessagesControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/ResourceControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/LocationControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/StaffController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DepartmentControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/OtherControllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DatePickerInputController.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<!-- Lazy loading -->
<script>
    window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: "eoo7q8o9",
        user_id: '{{{ Auth::user()->id }}}',
        name: '{{{ Auth::user()->first_name }}} {{{ Auth::user()->surname }}}',
        email: '{{{ Auth::user()->email }}}',
        user_type: '{{{ Auth::user()->getUserType() }}}',
        company: '{{{  Auth::user()->getCompany()->name }}}'
    };
</script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var w = window;
        var ic = w.Intercom;
        if (typeof ic === "function") {
            ic('reattach_activator');
            ic('update', intercomSettings);
        } else {
            var d = document;
            var i = function () {
                i.c(arguments)
            };
            i.q = [];
            i.c = function (args) {
                i.q.push(args)
            };
            w.Intercom = i;
            function l() {
                var s = d.createElement('script');
                s.type = 'text/javascript';
                s.async = true;
                s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/eoo7q8o9';
                var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
            }

            if (w.attachEvent) w.attachEvent('onload', l);
            else w.addEventListener('load', l, false);
        }
    })()
</script>

@endsection
```

Comment: It's indeed better with some code to help you

Comment: Start by showing the page where you reference angular.min.js :)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765941/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-when-i-include-jquery

Comment: I saw this post, but the answers didn't help me... I updated with some code, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're loading third party libraries twice

```
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-load.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-jq.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/timer.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-load.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-jq.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-tree.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/timer.js"></script>
```

Comment: OMG, I didn't see that !!! Thank you so much ! I probably did a CTRL+D not on purpose a long time ago ^^.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple reasons to this. Can you show your routing code? These errors are often caused due to mix of routes or improper handling of the routing.

Comment: What was the downvote reason? I think that is the legitimate answer.