# UpgradeModule error on angular-cli

Tags: angular

I tried to use UpgradeModule to bootstrap my app so I can use anglarJS components from Angular.  But I keep on getting the following error in console.  Please advise.  I am using angular-cli to package my app.  Do I need to add angular in package.json? Cause even if I did, I still got the error.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: AngularJS v1.x is not loaded! ; Zone:
>    ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ZoneAwareError
>   {__zone_symbol__error: Error: AngularJS v1.x is not loaded!
>       at Object.noNg (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem today and solved by loading `AngularJS` as a **Global script**.

As described in the [angular-cli's wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts):

> You can add Javascript files to the global scope via the `apps[0].scripts` property in `.angular-cli.json`. These will be loaded exactly as if you had added them in a  tag inside `index.html`.
>
> This is especially useful for legacy libraries or analytic snippets.
>
> ```
> "scripts": [
>   "global-script.js",
> ],
> ```

So, basically you just have to add `"../node_modules/angular/angular.js"` to the `app` > `scripts` in the `.angular-cli.json` file.

After doing this, the app builds and works. One small caveat though, is that it now shows **`WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`** in the console, which can be [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499853/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-angular-js) [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765941/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-when-i-include-jquery), but not an error anymore.

I'll update the answer if/when I find out.

Comment: The warning of loading angular twice might be related to the point where it mentions not using `import * as angular from 'angular'` but rather just declaring it as an available variable so TypeScript can compile, i.e. using `declare var angular: any`, see the section [Using global libraries inside your app](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts#using-global-libraries-inside-your-app)